# ORACLE - Set the length for a varchar2 length based on a query

Tags: sql, oracle, select, varchar2

I am trying to use the `CAST` function to convert the output of a column in a query, from `VARCHAR2`(255 CHAR) to `VARCHAR2` of a variable length, the final number being returned by a sub-query, like this:

```
SELECT CAST(Title as VARCHAR2(SELECT MAX(LENGTH(Title)) FROM Books)) 
FROM Books;
```

Does anyone know if it is possible for me to format the output as a VARCHAR2 with the length returned by the sub query? For the example above I keep getting errors but there might be other ways.

Comment: It does not make much sense casting to an unsized varchar2; if your column already is a varchar2, maybe you need no cast. What do you need to do? Please post relevant code you want to use this query in.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What's the problem that you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: The interest of `varchar2` is that it varies in length, ain't it? So why want to change its type to another like that? Are you looking for a way to remove extra spaces at the end? You could use `trim(Title)` to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible.

SQL by definition has a static type system, i.e. the number of result columns and their names and types are determined before the statement is run (and after the statement has been parsed).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with dynamic sql. A solution that works in SQL Developer is:

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;

DECLARE
  p_max_length INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX( LENGTH( title ) )
  INTO   p_max_length
  FROM   Books;

  OPEN :cur FOR
  'SELECT CAST( Title AS VARCHAR2(' || p_max_length || ')) FROM Books';
END;
/

PRINT cur;
```

However, I am having trouble understanding **why** you would want to do this as the title is already a `VARCHAR2(255)` (so already has variable length) and reducing the maximum capacity is not going to reduce the size of the data.

You can see they are the same by doing:

```
SELECT DUMP(Title) FROM Books;
```

and comparing it to the query above using this instead:

```
OPEN :cur FOR
'SELECT DUMP(CAST( Title AS VARCHAR2(' || p_max_length || '))) FROM Books';
```

and you will see that the data returned is identical in both cases.